# "ReactBingmaps" does not work with next - css file/module from node_modules is not supported

Tags: node.js, next.js

The code repo is here: https://github.com/jim-king-2000/nextbugrepro 
Steps to reproduce the behavior, please provide code snippets or a repository:

Create a sample next project. (see next.js tutorial)

```
npm i react-bingmaps
Add "import { ReactBingmaps } from 'react-bingmaps';" into "pages/index.js".
npm install --save @zeit/next-css
```

Create `next.config.js` and copy the following code:

```js
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

See the error:

```
./node_modules/react-bingmaps/lib/components/ReactBingmaps/ReactBingmaps.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
```

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
.react-bingmaps{
| width: 100%;
| height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/267) and [this](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/266) github issues.

As a temporary hack, try adding this to the top of your `next.config.js` file:

```
if (typeof require !== "undefined") {

 require.extensions[".css"] = () => {};

}
```